# Find polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that $f(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)$ where $r(x)=0$ or $\deg r(x)<\deg g(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Find polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that $f(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)$ where $r(x)=0$ or $\deg r(x)<\deg g(x)$ provided that $f(x)=2x^4+x^2-x+1$ and $g(x)=3x^2+2$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

The problem I'm having with this is that I can't think of any possible function in $\Bbb Z[x]$ that satisfies either of the conditions that the remainder $r(x)$ is $0$ or $\mbox{deg}(r(x))<\mbox{deg}(g(x))$.

Comment: Yes, but that is not possible in $\Bbb Z[x]$

Comment: Do long division on f and g, that is divide f by g until you have a remainder, the remainder is either 0 or a linear factor ax+b which is order 1, one less than g.  As a start, subtract 2/3 * x**2 of g from f.

Comment: Does the statement also require that $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ be in $\Bbb Z[x]$?

Comment: @cockneywanker, If you subtract $\frac23x^2$ of $g$ from $f$, 1) That'll be part of your remainder, and 2) you'll have a $\frac23x^2$ lying around, which is not in $\Bbb Z[x]$

Comment: @coldnumber, yes, that's part of the division algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ [is not a PID](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500254/is-mathbbzx-a-principal-ideal-domain), so it's not an [Euclidean domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain) and you can't *use* the division algorithm in general.

Comment: That's weird, it's a question on a worksheet that my professor provided. Must've been a typo.

Comment: maybe he means $\mathbb{Q}[x]$...