# What does the ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ generated by $x$ and $2$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

What does the ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ generated by $x$ and $2$ look like?

I don't know how to put it into terms of more explicit set notation

Comment: they are the polynomials with even constant coefficient.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate, but it is NOT. The questions are totally different. Please read the question before marking it as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element of $I=(2,x)$ will be exactly the same as any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, except for the constant coefficient being necessarily even.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, would it be correct to say that this ideal is principal?

Comment: No, the ideal $(2,x)$ can't be generated by just one polynomial, in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Note that only the coefficient of the term of degree zero must be even, any other coefficient can be odd.

Comment: $(2,x)$ is a notable example of a non-principal ideal, frequently used to show that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not a PID (an integral domain in which every ideal is principal). You can find a proof and further information here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500254/is-mathbbzx-a-principal-ideal-domain

Answer (score 6):

$I=(x,2)=\{xf+2g:f,g\in\mathbb{Z}[X]\}$

Comment: This is a good answer because it is generalizable  (+1).