# True/False regarding PIDs and UFDs

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The question is as follows:

> Which of the following statements are true?
>
> 1. $\Bbb Z[x]$ is a PID
> 2. $\Bbb Z[x,y]/\langle y+1 \rangle$ is a UFD
> 3. If $R$ is a PID and $\mathfrak p$ is a non-zero prime ideal, then $R/\mathfrak p$ has finitely many prime ideals
> 4. If $R$ is a PID, then any subring of $R$ containing $1$ is again a PID.
>
> (PID = principal ideal domain, UFD = unique factorization domain)

please somebody help me with this question
i know the first option is incorrect because Z is not a field
but the rest i dont know 
please help

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT TYPE IN CAPS. It makes it seem as though you're shouting.

Comment: 1. is a [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500254/is-mathbbzx-a-principal-ideal-domain).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2200723/279515 is the same question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

2) $\mathbf Z[x,y]/(y+1)$ is isomorphic to .....

3)  What can you say about a non-zero prime ideal in  a P.I.D.?

4) The subring of $\mathbf Q[x]$ of integer-valued polynomials is not noetherian (not sure this is the simplest possible answer for beginners…).

4) Simpler (thanks to @Omnomnomnom): See in question 1: $\;\mathbf Z[x]\subset \mathbf Q[x]$

Comment: For 4: question 1 already asks about $\Bbb Z[x]$ so there's no need to appeal to ascending chains.

Comment: Quite right. I'll add it as a hint (with due credits of course).

Comment: @Bernard Z[x,y]/(y+1) is isomorphic to which group

Comment: @Bernard.. a non zero prime ideal in PID is maxiaml

Comment: @suresh: working in $\mathbf zx,y]/(y+1)$ amounts to replace $y$ by $-1$ in  a polynomial $p(x,y)$. So you obtain the polynomial $p(x, -1)\in\mathbf Z[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1.) The Krull dimension of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is $\dim \mathbb{Z}+1$, and PID's have Krull dimension $0$ or $1$ (not sure this is the simplest possible answer for beginners, but elementary answers are already duplicates).

2.),3.),4.) Bernard.