# Which of the following is/are true in case of rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

> Which of the following is/are true.
>
> 1. $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain.
> 2. $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/\langle y+1 \rangle$ is a unique factorization domain.
> 3. If $R$ is a PID and $p$ is a non-zero prime ideal, then $R/p$ has finitely many prime ideals.
> 4. If $R$ is a PID, then any subring of $R$ containing 1 is again a PID.

Option 1 is obviously false. Also for option 3, since $R$ is a PID, so $R/p$ is a field and field has only one prime ideal. So option 3 is true. But I have no clue how to solve option 2 and 4. Can anybody help me with these? Thanks.

Comment: Option 2 is true -- the quotient is isomorphic to [what ring]?

Comment: Option 4 is false. Consider the subring A = Q[x^2,x^3] of B = Q[x]. The ring B is a PID, but the subring A isn't, since it's not a UFD (consider the two obvious factorizations of x^6 in the ring A).

Comment: For option 2, define the actual isomorphism, and prove that it's an isomorphism (routine verification).

Comment: Another reason $4$ is obviously wrong: fields are all PIDs, and every domain embeds in its field of fractions... obviously not all domains are PIDs.

Answer (score 7):

You can use (the falsity of) (1) to aid in (4). The ring $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ is a PID, but contains $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ as a subring containing $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Since [@BenWest has shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2200742/279515) that option 4 is false, I will only talk about option 2 in my answer.

For option 2, consider the map $\phi \colon \mathbb{Z}[x,y] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]$ defined by $$\phi(f(x,y)) = f(x,-1).$$ $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism with $$\ker(\phi) = \{ f(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y] : f(x,-1) = 0 \}.$$ We will show that the kernel is the principal ideal $(y+1)$. This will imply, from the first isomorphism theorem, that $\operatorname{im}(\phi) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y+1)$, which gives an explicit description of the quotient.

Now, let $f(x,y) \in \ker(\phi)$. View $f$ as lying in $\mathbb{Z}[y][x]$. So, $f(x,y) = a_0(y) + a_1(y) x + \dots + a_n(y) x^n$, for some $a_i(y) \in \mathbb{Z}[y]$. Therefore, $f(x,-1) = 0 \implies a_i(-1) = 0$ for all $i \implies (y+1) \mid a_i(y)$ for all $i \implies f(x,y) = (y+1) g(x,y)$ for some $g(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. Conversely, every element in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ of the form $(y+1)k(x,y)$ lies in $\ker(\phi)$. Hence, $\ker(\phi) = (y+1)$.

Thus, $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y+1) \cong \operatorname{im}(\phi) = \{ f(x,-1) : f(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y] \}$. Obviously, $\operatorname{im}(\phi) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Conversely, if $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, then we define $g(x,y) := f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, so $g(x,-1) = f(x) \in \operatorname{im}(\phi)$. Hence, $\mathbb{Z}[x] \subseteq \operatorname{im}(\phi)$.

Thus, $\operatorname{im}(\phi) = \mathbb{Z}[x]$, which is a UFD. Therefore, option 2 is true.